# Shell script of mysqldump works fine when run manually, but does not run in the cron job?

Tags: mysql, cron, mysqldump

I have a shell script to get a MySQL database dump. This script works fine when run manually

```
#!/bin/sh
fqn=/home/Mysqluser/daily_dumps/bookstore_`date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S`.sql.gz
mysqldump -u root -h localhost -pmysql#passwd bookstore | gzip > $fqn
```

But when I include this script to be run in cron job, it doesnt make the backup.

This is what I included in the cron job:

```
00 00 * * *  /home/Mysqluser/daily_dumps/bin/backup_database.sh
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably because the environment(s) (type `env` at prompt to see it) are different.

I had similar problem trying to run a mysql query in cron.daily, I solved it by adding this flag `--defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf`

It look like mysqldump has a similar flag `--defaults-extra-file` (needs to be first argument) but if that doesn't work try to to find out what is the difference between your command-line environment and cron environment. Create a cronjob that prints the output of `env` to a file and compare it to what you get when you run it from your shell.

Comment: I had something similar on running a php script through cron. The cron job was set to run as my user account, but when we delved further, the php being invoked under cron was from a completely different directory and therefore not running under the same php.ini as my interactive user account.

Answer (score 0):

Also, be sure that `mysqldump` is in the `$PATH` when running from cron. A best practice is to set `$PATH` directly in your script, or to specify full paths to any commands that are invoked (e.g., `/usr/bin/mysqldump`).